# How to insert copied text or images by right click in Google Docs editors

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-slides

In Google Docs editors, is there a way to allow pasting by right click and selecting paste? Why do they disabled this feature by default? Sometimes it’s faster than pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> if your hand is already on the mouse and you just copied text from another tab or program.

Comment: I replaced Google Drive by "Google Docs editors" because Google Drive is the name of the online file management and it doesn't allow copy and paste of files like could be done in Microsoft Windows. Google Docs editors is the name used by Google for their productivity suite. See http://support.google.com/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time right click shows a context menu that include paste as an option. Just do right click over an editable area in a document, spreadsheet or presentation.

[image: Context menu]

Comment: I think this is new as it used to give the message press Ctrl+V to paste.

Comment: @Celeritas: that's why I started with "At this time..." :)

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @Celeritas I just tried in Windows 8.1 Firefox 39 and it worked fine.

Comment: On my home computer it still says I need to use the keyboard short cuts.

Comment: @Celeritas: In  [Web App <X> isn't working correctly. How can I fix it?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79171/web-app-x-isnt-working-correctly-how-can-i-fix-it) there are some hints about things to try.